# Calculating similarity measure between millions of documents

Tags: python, performance, scalability, similarity

I have millions of documents(close to 100 million), each document has fields such as `skills`, `hobbies`, `certification` and `education`. I want to find similarity between each document along with a score.

Below is an example of data.

```
skills  hobbies        certification    education
Java    fishing        PMP              MS
Python  reading novel  SCM              BS
C#      video game     PMP              B.Tech.
C++     fishing        PMP              MS
```

so what i want is similarity between first row and all other rows, similarity between second row and all other rows and so on. So, every document should be compared against every other document. to get the similarity scores.

Purpose is that i query my database to get people based on skills. In addition to that, i now want people who even though do not have the skills, but are somewhat matching with the people with the specific skills. For example, if i wanted to get data for people who have JAVA skills, first row will appear and again, last row will appear as it is same with first row based on similarity score.

**Challenge**: My primary challenge is to compute some similarity score for each document against every other document as you can see from below pseudo code. How can i do this faster? Is there any different way to do this with this pseudo code or is there any other computational(hardware/algorithm) approach to do this faster?

```
document = all_document_in_db
For i in document:
   for j in document:
      if i != j :
        compute_similarity(i,j)
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to speed up would be to ensure you don't calculate similarity both ways. your current pseudocode will compare `i` to `j` *and* `j` to `i`. instead of iterating `j` over the whole document, iterate over `document[i+1:]`, i.e. only entries after `i`. This will reduce your calls to `compute_similarity` by half.

The most suitable data structure for this kind of comparison would be an adjacency matrix. This will be an `n * n` matrix (`n` is the number of members in your data set), where `matrix[i][j]` is the similarity between members `i` and `j`. You can populate this matrix fully while still only half-iterating over `j`, by just simultaneously assigning `matrix[i][j]` and `matrix[j][i]` with one call to `compute_similarity`.

Beyond this, I can't think of any way to speed up this process; you will need to make at least `n * (n - 1) / 2` calls to `compute_similarity`. Think of it like a handshake problem; if every member must be compared to ('shake hands with') every other member at least once, then the lower bound is `n * (n - 1) / 2`. But I welcome other input!

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want is some sort of clustering algorithm.  You think of each row of your data as giving a point in a multi-dimensional space.  You then want to look for other 'points' that are nearby.  Not all the dimensions of your data will produce good clusters so you want to analyze your data for which dimensions will be significant for generation of clusters and reduce the complexity of looking for similar records by mapping to a lower dimension of the data.  [scikit-learn](https://www.scikit-learn.org) has some good routines for dimensional analysis and clustering as well as some of the best documentation for helping you to decide which routines to apply to your data.  For actually doing the analysis I think you might do well to purchase cloud time with AWS or Google AppEngine.  I believe both can give you access to Hadoop clusters with Anaconda (which includes scikit-learn) available on the nodes.  Detailed instructions on either of these topics (clustering, cloud computing) are beyond a simple answer.  When you get stuck post another question.

Comment: This sounds like a viable solution.

Comment: great response for the higher-level problem here. clustering algorithms do not need to compute every individual pairwise distance, so will not require the hundreds of billions of comparisons.

Comment: you will have to think about how you encode your categories, however. since clustering depends on 'distance' in multidimensional space, you cannot just pass strings as features. when mapping strings to values, there must be some order imposed on the strings. for example, an 'education' of GED is closer to bachelors than to masters, and even farther from PhD. you will need to set up a mapping for each category, e.g. GED = 1, BS = 2, MS = 3, PhD = 4. This will allow you to perform clustering while accurately representing the features of your data.

Comment: @JasonStein, what if degrees are a mix of free text (Bachelors in computer science, Bachelors in Information technology, Bachelors in Arts, Masters in Sociology) and acronym BS, BA, MA etc?

Comment: @Enthusiast: You just set up your encoding dictionary to map multiple strings to the same value.  `encd = { 'GED':1, 'Bachelors in Arts':2, 'BA':2` etc.  You have to do an analysis on the column to find all the different strings present. With 100MM rows I suspect there is a significant amount of junk.  Maybe use a `collections.defaultdict` to map junk to 0.

Answer (score 1):

With 100 mln document, you need 500,000 bln comparisons. No, you cannot do this in Python.

The most feasible solution (aside from using a supercomputer) is to calculate the similarity scores in C/C++.

1. Read the whole database and enumerate each skill, hobby, certification, and education. This operation takes a linear time, assuming that your index look-ups are "smart" and take constant time.
2. Create a C/C++ `struct` with four numeric fields: skill, hobby, certification, and education.
3. Run a nested loop that subtracts each `struct` from all other `struct`s fieldwise and uses bit-level arithmetic to assess the similarity.
4. Save the results into a file and make them available to the Python program, if necessary.

Comment: One more reason for me to learn C++ Thanks for your valuable input!!

Comment: Can Spark be used for this type of task?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe you need to compute a matrix representation of the documents and only call the compute_similarity once. This will invoke a vectorized implementation of the algo on all pairs of rows of features in the X matrix (the first parameter assuming sci-kit learn). You'll be surprised by the performance. If the attempt to calculate this in one call exceeds your RAM you can try to chunk.